# Time and events in a Cox model

Tags: survival, cox-model, hazard

I am going to perform survival analysis using the Cox model, but I have some doubts about the input data.

The data have the following structure:

```
|| id.patient || Age || Event || Time (days) || other covariates ||
```

- id.patient: numeric ID
- Age: age of the patient Event: 0= (alive), 1=(death),  2=(censored)
- Time: days until event ... but I have time just for event 1 and 2...for the patients alive at the end of the study I haven't the time variable.
- Other covariates: other measures related to the patients.

My questions are:

1) Can I perform the Cox model having 3 types of Events?

2) If yes, how can I perform a Cox model without having time for alive patients?

Any suggestions? Could you kindly provide examples in R?

Comment: Need to derive the time if time is missing. For the patients still alive, the time = the last time knowing being alive - time of beginning, generally.

Comment: @user158565 thanks...and about the presence of three kinds of events?

Comment: censoring = alive.